# xslt 1.0 how to test for numbers

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I test if value of element is a number / is castable to number?

What I need to do is to copy value if it is a number, and substitute it with 99 if it is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the 'number' function -

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_number.html

Answer (score 3):

string(number($x)) = 'NaN' tests whether $x is castable to a number.

Answer (score 1):

**In addition to the correct answer by** @Michael Kay:

```
number($x) = number($x)
```

**this expression is `true()` exactly when `$x` is castable to a number**

Here we use the fact that:

1. If `$x` isn't a number, then `number($x)` by definition is `NaN`
2. `NaN` isn't equal to any value, even to `NaN`

**Now, your final question**:

> What I need to do is to copy value if it is a number, and substitute
>   it with 99 if it is a string

**Use**:

```
  $x * (number($x) = number($x))
+
  99 * not(number($x) = number($x))
```

**Explanation**:  A boolean is converted to number (`true()`  --> 1, `false()` --> 0) when part of a numeric expression. In the above expression one of the arguments of `+` will be `0` and one will be `1` depending on whether `$x` isn't/is a number.